# "using something else from" or "using something else than"

Tags: phrases, expressions

Which of these makes better sense.

`I can use something else from wood.` - This one doesn't sound right, or does it?

`I can use something different from wood.` - Same as the former, but it sounds a bit better. Is it correct though?

The following all sound right enough, so I'll consider them as correct.

`I can use something different than wood.`

`I can use something else than wood.`

`I can use something other than wood.`

Please correct/improve my tags as I'm not sure what to call the aforementioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/ I can use something else from wood.
*This first one is not correct at all. A correct formulation is as follows.*

*I can use something else **than** wood.      [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=something+else+than&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csomething%20else%20than%3B%2Cc0)*

2/  I can use something different from wood.
*This second one is quite correct. It is the traditional form (British English) an it is used much more than the two more recent forms that follow.     [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=different+from%2Cdifferent+than%2Cdifferent+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdifferent%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdifferent%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdifferent%20to%3B%2Cc0)*

- *I can use something different **than** wood.*
- *I can use something different **to** wood.*

3/ I can use something other than wood.
*This third form is correct.*

Answer (score 1):

There is this phrase, shown by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/other_than) as

> **other than**
>   PHRASE
>
> **1.1** Differently or different from; otherwise than.
>   *there is no suggestion that we are to take this other than literally*

So your sentence can be

> I can use something **other than** wood.

Comment: I should probably be using `other than`. But is `else from` a valid option?

Comment: With a shorter sentence: "I can use something else."